# Multiple Input [type=file] on same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one input here that can upload a file into a div as it's background image. But how would I add a second input [type=file] that could upload a second image into a second div?

The second file that I want to upload is called:

```
<input type='file' id='getval' name="logo" />
```

And I want to place that file as the background-image of the div called:

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

here's the whole thing:

```js
document.getElementById('getval').addEventListener('change', readURL, true);
function readURL(){
   var file = document.getElementById("getval").files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onloadend = function(){
      document.getElementById('adXL').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";        
   }
   if(file){
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }else{
    }
}
```

```css
h2 {
font-size: 14px;
margin: 14px 0 3px;
}

#adXL{
   background-image:url('');
   background-size:cover;
   background-position: center;
min-height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
   border: 0px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}


#logo{
   background-image:url('');
   background-size:cover;
   background-position: center;
  min-width: 0;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h2>Background Image</h2>
<input type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" />
<h2>logo</h2>
<input type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" />

<div id='adXL'>
<div id='logo'>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: dont re-use IDs in HTML, that's not what they are there for.

Comment: `var file = this.files[0];`

Comment: ok, so how would I change it in order to be able to add a second file?

Comment: where would that go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, **never** re-use IDs in HTML.

```
document.getElementById('getval').addEventListener('change', readURL, true);
function readURL(){
   var file = document.getElementById("getval").files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onloadend = function(){
      document.getElementById('adXL').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";        
   }
   if(file){
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }else{
    }
}

document.getElementById('getval2').addEventListener('change', readURL2, true);
function readURL2(){
   var file2 = document.getElementById("getval2").files[0];
   var reader2 = new FileReader();
   reader2.onloadend = function(){
      document.getElementById('logo').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader2.result + ")";        
   }
   if(file2){
      reader2.readAsDataURL(file2);
    }else{
    }
```

Comment: this breaks the first input[type=file]

Comment: Can you run it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @johnny555 please check my updated answer, replace that code with your exisiting functions. should work.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding eventListner add change attribute to your input file and call the function readURL(). You can then pass parameters and reuse the function.

```js
function readURL(input,output){
   var file = document.getElementById(input.id).files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onloadend = function(e){
      document.getElementById(output).style.backgroundImage = "url('" + reader.result + "')";        
   }
   if(file){
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }else{
    }
}
```

```css
h2 {
font-size: 14px;
margin: 14px 0 3px;
}

#adXL{
   background-image:url('');
   background-size:cover;
   background-position: center;
min-height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
   border: 0px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}


#logo{
   background-image:url('');
   background-size:cover;
   background-position: center;
  min-width: 0;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h2>Background Image</h2>
<input type='file' id='getval' onchange="readURL(this, 'adXL')" name="background-image" />
<h2>logo</h2>
<input type='file' id='getval' onchange="readURL(this, 'logo')" name="background-image" />

<div id='adXL'>
<div id='logo'>
</div>
</div>
```